# Можно ли в xml создавать переменные, которые потом подставляются в другие части файла?

Tags: xml

У меня проект в котором надо создать 30 файлов xml в каждом из которых прописано по 5 путей. Можно ли создать переменную которая будет подставляться далее в файле?

Пример желаемого:

```
var directory = "C:\dir\dir2"

<project>
    <junitreport todir= directory\report>
    </junitreport>
    <junitreport todir= directory\result>
    </junitreport>
</project>
```

Comment: Какой язык программирования ?

Comment: никакой. Я думал xml сам по себе поддеоживает такую функцию. Его зачитывает Ant. Это build.xml

Comment: XML это формат разметки для хранения данных, в нем нет ничего подобного, это просто текст и не более.

Comment: @S.G.  читайте например тут  http://msiter.ru/tutorials/uchebnik-xml-dlya-nachinayushchih/chto-takoe-xml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В качестве переменных можно использовать сущности (entities).

В данном примере объявляем сущность `directory` с нужным значением. Далее используем её в виде `&directory;`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE project [
  <!ENTITY directory "C:\dir\dir2">
]>
<project>
  <junitreport todir= "&directory;\report">
  </junitreport>
  <junitreport todir= "&directory;\result">
  </junitreport>
</project>
```

Comment: спасибо, работает. Нашел еще сам второй вариант.

Answer (score 3):

Нашел сам еще второй вариант с property:

```
<project>
    <property name="project_directory" value="C:\dir\dir2" />

    <junitreport todir= "${project_directory}\report">
    </junitreport>
    <junitreport todir= "${project_directory}\result">
    </junitreport>
</project>
```